# ggplot - create a graph with two x-axes: one categorical and one continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a graph like this one
[image] but have the points in each bin ordered by two continuous variables.

So I made a dataset that looks like this:

```
Cell   X-axis Y-axis
X       No      Yes
Y      Yes       No
Z       No      Yes
M       No       No
```

and got the graph I wanted with `geom_jitter()`

Now, I would like to take each bin (e.g. "No"/"No") and order points not randomly, but have a continuous variable within the bin on both the x and y axis.
How can I do that?
I know I can use `sec_axis` but if it's always a transformation of the current axis, which is categorical, would that work?

Comment: I think `facet_grid` is what you are looking for: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to do it without it

Comment: Could you please upload output from `dput(yourDataFrame` in your question so that we can build a plot